QGIS Attribute Table has length .00000000000000 after all numbers
Basically I can't seem to truncate it down to only 2 decimal places

Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Questions here are expect to take several paragraphs and include screen captures or other relevant details. It's recommended that you write the entire Question first, then write the title afterward, as summation of the topic of the Question.

What dataset type are you using?

Variant 1: Copy of the field on the same layer
Use Field Calculator to create a new field and set field precision to the desired precision, e.g. 1 for one decimal (or select output field type integer for no decimals). As expression, insert the name of the initial field to get a copy of the field on the same layer.
Variant 2: Changed field precision on a copy of the layer
Use Refactor fields to change the precision of your field. The result will be output as a copy of the initial layer with the changes you defined.
